# Why is one ko.mapping.fromJS working and other one not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a class a class named Foo and Foo contains Model. I am doing a ko.applyBinding on Foo. The Foo class has a function which retrieves JSON from server and then I do:

```
 self.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
```

where self is instance of Foo and result is JSON. This works 1st time. However, when 2nd item I retrieve data from server it just doesn't work.

But if the above line to:

```
 self.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);
```

it works.

Can anybody tell me why is the 1st one not working and 2nd one works?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second line should be:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self.Model);
```